# fail to get different values from 2 divs with same class

Tags: jquery, html, for-loop

I have 2 divs with same class, but they have different values in them.
I am trying to use the different values in a jquery loop but for some reason the script only uses the value from the first div.

here is the [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GsK96/)

html:

```
<div class="temp-stars"><p>5</p></div>
<div class="temp-stars"><p>2</p></div>
```

css:

```
.temp-stars { position: relative; background: #666; padding: 10px; width: 100px; height: 10px; }
.temp-stars p {display: none;}
.stars {position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.single-star-yellow { width: 10px; height: 10px; background: #f90; float: left; margin-right:5px; }
```

jquery:

```
$(function () {
    var num = parseInt($(".temp-stars p").html());
    alert(num)
    $(".temp-stars").append("<div class='stars'></div>")
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        $(".stars").append("<div class='single-star-yellow'></div>")

    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
$(".temp-stars").each(function () {
    var num = parseInt($(this).find("p").html());

    var $star = $("<div class='stars'></div>").appendTo(this)
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        $star.append("<div class='single-star-yellow'></div>")
    };
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/U3VFE/)

You have used the getter version of `.html()` to get the `num` value, it will always return the value of the first element in the given set of elements.

You need to use a loop like the above one to solve it.

---

Little more nerdy

```
$(".temp-stars").each(function () {
    var num = +$(this).find("p").html();

    $("<div class='stars'></div>").append(new Array(num + 1).join("<div class='single-star-yellow'></div>")).appendTo(this)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/U3VFE/3/)

Comment: Thank you. this works perfectly well. I actually did try to use the each function, but viewing your code I understand that I had alot of stuff missing in my attempt.